# Search specific call tree in call hierarchy result?

Tags: java, eclipse, call-hierarchy

If I search the call hierarchy of any `method(method_A)` in eclipse, I get more than 100 references.

I want to search specific call tree in this result where `method_A` is called by a specific method (`method_Z`), how can I do that?

At present, I need to go through all 100 results which is very time consuming and frustrating.